# Send Direct Messages using twitter API

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-oauth

I trying to use twitter API to send direct messages using C# but Twitter keeps saying:

"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

But this has no sense because I could use other API calls where I was authorized.

Some background info:

I created an application with these access permissions: Read, Write and Access direct messages

I could succesfully post a status in my timeline:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update

I could also retrieve all the direct messages sent to me:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/direct_messages

The problem is when I try to send a direct message:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/direct_messages/new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't figure out yet what's wrong, but I could make it work using a open source project called tweetsharp. You can download it and see the code that works:

[Tweet Sharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp)

here is a code example

```
    var service = new TwitterService(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
var user = service.VerifyCredentials();
var result = service.SendDirectMessage(recipient, message);
```

Comment: I'm (desperately I might add ;) looking for a codesampe how to get this to work. Your code sample looks good, but to get the `accessToken` value filled, the user has to enter a pin right? I have no idea how to set this up. Could you please share your full code as your answer? It would help me a lot!

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that you are following the message recipient and that they are following you? This must be the case before you can DM a person.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Although, in my test the recipient of the DM was myself. I could do this properly using twitter web interfase but I couldn't achieve it using the API.

Comment: Nop, this is not the case. I tested with an user that I'm following and he follows me and didn't work either.

Comment: OK cool, then maybe check this post from twitter: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/application-permission-model